# Should I use a JavaScript array on a website to store item data from a database?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

Would it be appropriate to use a JavaScript array on a website to store item data (from the database) about the items that the user has added to the cart? I was thinking, once the user has committed to the purchase, then send this array data to firestore database. I am making a food ordering website for the first time, so I am not sure what the best approach would be. At first, I began sending every item that the user had added to the cart to firestore, but then I thought it might be better to just create an array with JavaScript for these items before sending them to firestore. My thinking is, once the user opens the website, the array would be ready to start storing items added to cart, then if the user decides to exit, that array would be gone, avoiding sending data to firestore. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work okay IMO as long as you are okay that the user's cart would not persist in the same session. For example, if the user accidentally or purposefully closes the window/tab and then comes back, the cart will be empty.

Comment: Yes, I am okay with that. In fact, that is why I wanted to go this route so I wouldn't have data in the database that was not necessary (if the user decided to exit out and never came back, or came back with wanting to order different items), and having to write code to delete that data. Also, for the same array to work on the multiple web pages (in the same website), what would be the best approach?

Comment: To persist it only within the browser, you can look into Local Storage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage